# How to apply this image fullscreen and make it responsive to any screen

Tags: html, css

Here is the I'm editing right now.
[image]

I want the images to be stretched removing the white lines on both sides and make it responsive to any different screen. I tried every code but it doesn't seem to work. Below is the code I'm using right now.

```html
<div class="aff1">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4mpnwdX/01.jpg" alt="Afiiliate 1" style="display: flex; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%;" />
</div>
<div class="aff2">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/QJ3gmqz/02.jpg" alt="Affiliate 2" style="display: flex; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%" />
</div>
<div class="aff3">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NpBKjPJ/03.jpg" alt="Affiliate 3" style="display: flex; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers add default styling to some elements. For example if you inspect the body element in your browser's dev tools facility you will probably see there is a margin set by the system.

You can remove all the default margins (and other things if needed) by putting a setting at the top of your stylesheet.

This snippet demonstrates this using your code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="aff1">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4mpnwdX/01.jpg" alt="Afiiliate 1" style="display: flex; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%;" />
</div>
<div class="aff2">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/QJ3gmqz/02.jpg" alt="Affiliate 2" style="display: flex; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%" />
</div>
<div class="aff3">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NpBKjPJ/03.jpg" alt="Affiliate 3" style="display: flex; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%" />
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this and tried using the div on the website for the container, but the image wasn't stretching after that. But it's responsive.

Comment: 'The image wasn't stretching after that' - setting the margin and padding to zero would not affect the image 'stretching' - it would have made no difference to how it was styled apart from removing those two settings. Could you explain a bit more what you mean by stretching? I doubt you want the image to actually stretch (it could beome distorted). You may be looking for cover as a setting.

Comment: Retried this code, and it did the work. Idk why last night won't work lol. And I changed something with regards to the styles. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Remove other styles from image. Width:100% stretches images and max-width:100% makes images responsive.

```
 <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NpBKjPJ/03.jpg" alt="Affiliate 3" style="width:100%;max-width:100%;" />
```

Comment: The image is responsive even with those other styles. But the image wasn't stretching to hide the white bars on both sides. Should I re-edit the image to the exact window resolution?

Comment: Can you share the full html code and css please

Comment: I have it fixed @Ercan Güven thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    body{
        margin: 0;
    }
    img{
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>



<div class="aff1">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4mpnwdX/01.jpg" alt="Afiiliate 1">
</div>
<div class="aff2">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/QJ3gmqz/02.jpg" alt="Affiliate 2" />
</div>
<div class="aff3">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NpBKjPJ/03.jpg" alt="Affiliate 3" />
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this, still doesn't make the image stretched to remove the white bars. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the full code @isuckatcoding_

Comment: I have it fixed now @Abhijith Surendran thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the width and height of the images to 100%

```html
<style>
*{
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
  Width:100%;
  padding:0;
}
</style>
<div class="aff1">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4mpnwdX/01.jpg" alt="Afiiliate 1" style="display: flex; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%;" />
</div>
<div class="aff2">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/QJ3gmqz/02.jpg" alt="Affiliate 2" style="display: flex; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%" />
</div>
<div class="aff3">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NpBKjPJ/03.jpg" alt="Affiliate 3" style="display: flex; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `background-size:cover` to the img attribute

```
img{
    background-size:cover;
    }
```

```html
<style>
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}
img{
background-size:cover;
}
</style>
<div class="aff1">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4mpnwdX/01.jpg" alt="Afiiliate 1" style="display: flex; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%;" />
</div>
<div class="aff2">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/QJ3gmqz/02.jpg" alt="Affiliate 2" style="display: flex; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%" />
</div>
<div class="aff3">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NpBKjPJ/03.jpg" alt="Affiliate 3" style="display: flex; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%" />
</div>
```